# Send survey link via email from Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I would like to send a email out of firebase when ever a child is added to a particular destination in Firebase Database. That email should contain a link and if you click on the link a value in firebase should change.

I found similar functionality with the email confirmation in Firebase but I couldn’t find a way to use it for that case.

Comment: You could code up a solution with Cloud Functions.

Comment: @DougStevenson [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) can handle the triggering from the database but won't the OP also need a service to actually send the email such as Sendgrid? [SendGrid Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/sendgrid)? Or can Cloud Functions actually send the email as well?

Answer (score 0):

Emails sent through firebase are only for authentication. The functionality you are looking for is not possible without other services.